# Filtering Page URLs in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have created a custom report which contains

- Page (url),
- Page Title,
- Visitor Duration,
- Bounce Rate

I am using Adwords for advertising and want to see which pages get more hit and visit duration. When I view my custom report some of the page URLs looks like 
`"/tr-url/en-ru.ru/www.domain.com/corporate/about-us/"` so I am having 3-4 different hit for about-us page.

Is there a filter to get only the real page URL like `/about-us`, `/contact`, `/company-info` ?

Thanks in advance